# I cant use auxiliary functions from zephyr ( tty.h) file

Tags: c, tty, zephyr-rtos

I am building a project and I have the board stm nucleo_l496zg. All i want to do is to use the drivers from the board in order to communicate the board after west flash with minicom, it is a simple string transfer and response program. I am building this project with **zephyr** and my issue is that I cant use the functions tty_init , tty_read and tty_set_rx_buf despite that I use the proper include `" #include <console/tty.h> "`. The compiler returns an undefined reference to thoose three functions but in my program I am using another one function from tty.h header which is tty_set_timeout but at this function it doesnt say nothing. Though I notiched in that [in here(documentation of tty.h)](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/apidoc/latest/tty_8h_source.html) tty_Set_timeout is the only function that has something inside. I cant understand why I am getting that please if someone can help me let me know !

Comment: Have your tried building the console sample?
It is the minimum exmaple you're asking for I thing ;)
https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/samples/subsys/console/getline/README.html

Comment: @PaulWürtz yes i tied that but the specific orders I have got is to use tty ( drivers ) , do you know why is this happening ?

Comment: Have you enabled the correct peripherals/pinmuxing in your KConfig and device tree overlay? Which uart do you want to use? I have not used the tty myself, but I am sure you have to enable it in your KConfig file ^^

Comment: @PaulWürtz hmm  in Kconfig only I am using some definitions for the arrays , can you show me an example of how to enable it ? am using usart2  from the board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solve it by adding those lines to my .conf file:

```
CONFIG_SERIAL=y
CONFIG_STDOUT_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_UART_INTERRUPT_DRIVEN=y
CONFIG_CONSOLE_SUBSYS=y
CONFIG_CONSOLE_GETCHAR=y
```

And don't forget to mention the file (.conf file) also in your CMakeList.txt file:

```
set(CONF_FILE ***.conf)
```

Hope that it will work with you as well